# php echo base_url() bringing me to 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XY_NjpStgHg) to make a form to insert data to my database. I have come to a problem where my `<?php echo base_url()?>` is not linking to the form_validation page as it should. I have the config.php set to `$config['base_url'] = '';` and the autoload.php set to `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'html');` So I don't understand why I am getting the 404 error. Any help would be greatly advised.

### Model_ca.php

```
<?php

class Model_ca extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
    {

    parent::__construct();
    }

}

 ?>
```

### View_ca.php

```
 <html>
     <head> 
     <title>Add Chipper to Database</title>
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
     <body>
         <div class="container">
             <h3 align="center">Add Chipper to Database</h3>
             <!--Link form to base url which is defined in autoload.php-->
             <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>Controller_ca/form_validation">

               <div class="form-group">  
             <label>Enter Name</label>    
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Location</label>    
                <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Description</label>    
                <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control"/>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add Chipper" class="btn btn-info"/>
                 </div>

             </form>
         </div>

     </body>
 </html>
```

### Controller_ca.php

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller_ca extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');

    }

    public function index() 
    {  
        $this->load->view('View_ca');
    }    


public function form_validation()
{
    echo 'Form Validation is Working!';
}


}
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to close controllers and models with `?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config Should be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/path/to/folder/';
```

`.htaccess` should be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> Make sure rewrite rule is enabled in php.ini

Comment: Should it be `http://localhost/folder/Controller_ca` or `http://localhost/folder` ? Also can you explain the second part a bit more? Where do I put that code, I looked up the documentation but it doesn't say.

Comment: @cigarette_unicorn base url should look like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thanks

Comment: Thank you all for your help!