# htaccess doesnt remove index.php if WWW is in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, indexing

Using Htaccess, I am able to remove the www from the url but im struggling endlessly with completely removing the index.php.

I am using the codeigniter framework and I checked my config file.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Ive also tried: as someone suggested elsewhere on S.O:

```
$config['base_url'] = '/';
```

My htaccess file looked like this:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

```
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Ive tried all the different versions of writing the mode-rewrite rule, this one works the best but it adds a question mark to the URL and a forward slash
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The result at the moment, if i type www.mywebsite.com, it will change to mywebsite.com, which is correct.

But if I type www.mywebsite.com/someuri then it becomes www.mywebsite.com/index.php?someuri

with the last modrewrite rule the url becomes
www.mywebsite.com/?/someuri

I then tried adding the question mark after index.php like this:

```
# Now the CodeIgniter part
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

With the latter, if i type index.php into the URL, it doesnt go away.

I clearly dont understand mod-rewrite, can someone please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Probably because you have `[L,R=301]` in your forcing non-www rule.  The `L` indicates last rule, so don't process any further.  Try removing that from there.  I can't test it at the moment for it to be an answer, I'm not at a machine with Apache installed.

Comment: You might find this htaccess tester really handy  [http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: I removed [L] the result is still the same. It was worth a try though

Comment: Don;t leave base url blank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php echo base\_url() bringing me to 404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707849/php-echo-base-url-bringing-me-to-404)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Also `$config['base_url']` **Must** be set. e.g. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywebsite.com/';` (include the trailing slash)

Comment: Thank you, the solution you suggestion is one which ive tried before. It works. but if I add. www to the url then index.php? comes up. Also if i manually insert index.php in the URL then it remains, it does not get removed.

Comment: Codeigniter 3 versions do not have AUTO for uri_protocol

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

config base_url

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

to

```
$ark_root           = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ark_root          .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $ark_root;
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```